# Using a jQuery function for multiple divs

Tags: jquery, function

I have a div that contains a button with an ID.  When the button is clicked it calls some jQuery functions.

I am not sure how to add a 2nd div that also contains a button and allow the jQuery function to be used by either of them.

My HTML:

```
<div id="box" style="background:rgb(163, 205, 224); color:black; padding:15px;">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header" style=" border-radius: 5px;">
      <h2>
        IT helpdesk
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <ul id="favorite-links" style="list-style-type: none; padding:0;">
        <div id="text"></div>
        <li>
          <a href="http://artslab.info">Artslab</a><button class="removebtn">x</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="new-link-button">
        <button>Add New Link</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="add-link-form">
      <label>Title</label><br /><input id="title" placeholder="Title here" /><br /><label>URL</label><br /><input id="url" value="http://" /><br /><button id="add">Save Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $ul = $('#favorite-links');
  var $title = $('#title');
  var $url = $('#url');
  var $text = $('#text');

  //get items from local storage
  if (localStorage.getItem('vk-links')) {
    $ul.html(localStorage.getItem('vk-links'));
  }

  // add new item
  $('#add').click(function() {

    //add new item
    $('#favorite-links').append('<li><a href="' + $url.val() + '">' + $title.val() + '</a><button class="removebtn">x</button></li>');

    //save changes to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('vk-links', $ul.html());

    //reset form
    $title.val("");
    $url.val("http://");
    $("#add-link-form").slideToggle("100");

  });

  //remove item
  $("#favorite-links").on('click', '.removebtn', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    //save changes to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('vk-links', $ul.html());
  });

  //form toggle
  $("#new-link-button").click(function() {
    $("#add-link-form").slideToggle("100");
  });


  // reuse the same code for other div element such as the box 
  $("button").each(function(index) {
    //document
  });

});
```

I have made a jsFiddle here and would be very grateful for any help:

https://jsfiddle.net/shezellfoster/9xecvqd4/

Comment: You give them both a common class, and you select based on the common class, rather than on id(s)

Comment: You asked a question without asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is pretty big I made a small easier to read example of the concept.

- First you will use class selectors instead of id selectors so you can
  query multiple elements. Id's need to be unique (so change that in
  your html if you copy the div).
- Now we can use the class selector to assign a click element to all buttons.
- Inside the handler function we use the `this` variable to get the current pressed button.
- We look in which container this button is located and find the `p` element in
  here to change the text.

```js
$('.change').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.container').find('p').text('text changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container1" class="container">
  <p>Change this text</p>
  <button class="change">Change</button>
</div>

<div id="container2" class="container">
  <p>Change this text</p>
  <button class="change">Change</button>
</div>

<div id="container3" class="container">
  <p>Change this text</p>
  <button class="change">Change</button>
</div>
```

If you want to add multiple containers dynamically you will need to use event delegation. (or use `clone(true)`, but let's forget about that now)

```js
$('#dynamic_content').on('click', '.container', function() {
  $(this).closest('.container').find('p').text('text changed');
});

$('#clone').on('click', function() {
  $('#dynamic_content').children('.container').first().clone().appendTo('#dynamic_content');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic_content">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Change this text</p>
    <button class="change">Change</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="clone">clone</button>
```